# Completion of the squares (actually of the quadratic forms)

Tags: quadratic-forms

I have this paragraph in the book I cannot understand (this is not the first time I encounter this thing but I usually move on).

$$A^\prime TA+A^\prime QB+B^\prime UA+B^\prime RB = (A+T^{-1}QB)^\prime T(A+T^{-1}QB)+B^\prime (R-UT^{-1}Q)B$$

I can do the calculus in the reverse order, but I don’t know how is someone supposed to figure out how to do it, and I don’t understand why such a procedure is called “completing the squares”.

Can someone please elaborate on that?

NOTE: prime stands for transpose and those are all matrices.

Comment: Just curious, what book are you using?

Comment: Various: System Identification (Stoica), Estimation with application to tracking and navigation (Li, Bar-Shalon)...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:**
Completing the square for a quadratic polynomial of the form $ax^{2}+2bxy+dy^{2}$
is given by $$
a\left(x+\frac{b}{a}y\right)^{2}+\left(d-\frac{b^{2}}{a}\right)y^{2}.$$

If $A$ and $D$ are symmetric square matrices, and $B$ is $n \times m$, then

$$
\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
 x   \\
 y  \\
 \end{array} } \right]^T
\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
 A & B  \\
 B^T & D  \\
 \end{array} } \right]
\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
 x   \\
 y  \\
 \end{array} } \right] =  \left(x+A^{-1}By\right)^{T}A\left(x+A^{-1}By\right)+y^{T}\left(D-BA^{-1}B\right)y

$$
Note that the left hand side of your equation can be written as

$$
\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
 A^T & B^T  \\
  \end{array} } \right]
\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
 T & Q \\
 U & R  \\
 \end{array} } \right]
\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
 A   \\
 B  \\
 \end{array} } \right].  
$$

Hope this helps.